# Assuming $V=L$ show that any set of integers $x\in L_{\alpha+1}$ satisfies $x\in L_{\alpha}$ where $\alpha$ is countable.

Tags: set-theory

I can show that every set of integers is constructed at some countable stage of $L$. But apparently it's also true that any set of integers $x\in L_{\alpha+1}$ satisfies $x\in L_{\alpha}$ where $\alpha$ is countable.

I may be missing something obvious, but why is this true?

Comment: Yes, you're missing something obvious. That's it's not true. :)

Comment: Where did you see this claim?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Lecture notes. Do you see a possible typo that, if corrected, would make the statement true? I'm just trying to understand what my prof. had in mind.

Comment: Well, maybe it'd be a good idea to send an email to whomever wrote the lecture notes... Not just get a clarification, but also get them to correct their mistake for future readers and whatnot.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Fair point

Comment: Are you sure you asked the right question? What is true is that if $x$ is a set of integers and $x\in L$ (equivalently, $x\in L_{\alpha+1}$ for some ordinal $\alpha$), then there exists a countable ordinal $\alpha'$ (which may very well be different from $\alpha$) such that $x\in L_{\alpha'}$.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Right, that I know. ButI finally think I know what I should have asked. I'm going to post a new question now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is patently false. $\omega\in L_{\omega+1}$ but $\omega\notin L_\omega$. Or, $\varnothing\in L_1$ but $\varnothing\notin L_0$.

Generally, since limit steps do not add new sets, your claim would imply that the constructible hierarchy stabilized $\mathcal P(\omega)$ at the start, which is $\varnothing$. So... that's false.

Comment: Right, thank you.